# PySNMP returns TypeError with Anaconda install even with example code

Tags: python, pysnmp

I have installed Anaconda2.5 and it gives me Python 2.7.  I have installed the latest PySNMP. Initially, I attempted to run the Python script from another server using Python 2.6 on this one and got a TypeError (see below). I thought it must be because of my Python version, maybe something changed with PySNMP, but when I ran their example code (see below), it returned the exact same error.  I am baffled as to why their example code would return an error and can only suspect Anaconda installing PySNMP would be at fault?
This is the example code:

```
#!/root/anaconda2/python

from pysnmp.hlapi import *

for (errorIndication,
     errorStatus,
     errorIndex,
     varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                      CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
                      UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
                      ContextData(),
                      ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifDescr')),
                      ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifType')),
                      ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifMtu')),
                      ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifSpeed')),
                      ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifPhysAddress')),
                      ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifType')),
                      lexicographicMode=False):

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
    break
elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                        errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex)-1][0] or '?'))
    break
else:
    for varBind in varBinds:
        print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

This is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_aqx_intersite_bw.py", line 8, in 
    varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/engine.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.msgAndPduDsp = MsgAndPduDispatcher()
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/proto/rfc3412.py", line 29, in __init__
    'SNMP-TARGET-MIB', 'SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB'
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 337, in loadModules
    self.loadModule(modName, **userCtx)
  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 306, in loadModule
    'MIB module \"%s\" load error: %s' % (modPath, traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info()))
pysnmp.smi.error.MibLoadError: MIB module "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.pyc" load error: ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 301, in loadModule\n    exec(modData, g)\n', '  File "/home/ilan/minonda/envs/_build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.py", line 26, in \n', '  File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp/proto/rfc1902.py", line 201, in subtype\n    self, value, implicitTag, explicitTag, subtypeSpec\n', 'TypeError: subtype() takes at most 2 arguments (5 given)\n']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have something to do with the incompatible pysnmp/pyasn1 versions.

Depending on your situation you may want to either push both packages to their latest PyPI releases (`pip install --upgrade pysnmp pyasn1`) or, if you are stuck with your current pyasn1 version, downgrade pysnmp to perhaps 4.3.10.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am using Anaconda, so I did:

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am using Anaconda, so I did:
    conda upgrade pysnmp
    conda upgrade pyasn1

and it produced:

pysnmp                    4.3.2                    py27_0  
pyasn1                    0.3.7            py27haf6b024_0  

I have a working environment on another server with pysnmp=4.3.2 and pyasn1=0.1.9 where it works without a problem.  I created a conda environment with these specs and the error that was happening is gone.  (A new error has occurred, but that is another issue for me)   It seems your answer was correct in relation to that specific error.

Comment: Right, pyasn1-0.3.7 is way fresher compared to 0.1.9. So for example pysnmp-4.3.2 with pyasn1-0.1.9 or pysnmp-4.4.1 with pyasn1-0.3.7 are working combinations. There are many others, but the one you had initially is quite unbalanced version-wise. ;-)